# caolon async - callback never gets called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, coffeescript

I am using waterfall model to call list of functions one after the other. during upload req.on 'data' never gets called. below is the code. what is happening.

```
app.post '/upload', (req,res)->
    uploadFile = (cb)->
            req.on 'data', (chunk)->
                console.log "In the on data"+file ""NEVER GETS CALLED.
                console.log chunk
                file.write chunk
            req.on 'end', ->
                file.end()
                console.log "Wrote file"
                cb(null)

    async.waterfall [uploadFile],(err,result)->
```

Comment: If you're using `express.bodyParser`, that will already have read the incoming data. Also, in this example using `async.waterfall` isn't very useful.

Comment: The code was made simple to see through the problem(there are other routines that need to be called). Also there is no porblem of express.bodyParser as the code will work fine If I move it out of the async.waterfall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bufferedstream by mjijackson if you cannot upgrade to latest nodejs